# forEach method does not work

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Start" id="start">
```

JavaScript:

```
var inp = document.querySelectorAll('.z1');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inp, function(item, i, arr) {
      item[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert('fsdfs');
      }, false);
});

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',function() {
    var gg = '<input type="button" value="Button1" class="z1"><input type="button" value="Button2" class="z1">';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', gg);
});
```

The idea is that when you click on the inserted in the body INPUT should trigger alert.

Comment: What *does* happen? Nothing at all? An error in the browser console? Some other behaviour?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t5xz93tr/

Alert is not displayed.

Comment: The elements aren't there when `Array.prototype.forEach.call` is executed in this code. They get added by clicking while the call is fired before this click. There are simply `0` elements matching `.z1`

Comment: The problem is in the `item[i]` - see my solution below

Comment: `item[i]` is wrong as `item` would already be the dom element. So `item[i]` would be trying to access a property on the dom element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This updates your original code with a working version, it's even generic. Just pass selector string and it append the click function.

```
function setClickHandlers(selector)
{
    var inp = document.querySelectorAll(selector);  
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(inp, function(item, i, arr) {
          item.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerButton
          , false);
    }); 
}

    function clickHandlerButton()
    {
       alert('fsdfs');
    }

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',function() {
    var gg = '<input type="button" value="Button1" class="z1"><input type="button" value="Button2" class="z1">';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', gg);
    setClickHandlers('.z1');

});
```

To prevent your program from adding anonymous functions to each button you can reference a function in the click event. This saves some memory space and makes updates to the code easier.

However [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) has the most elegant solution, this requires only one click handler to be set. This works beautifully when elements have no children.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.

Comment: You've got a typo: an extra `}` before the `, false`.

Comment: won't this add multiple handlers as it targets all `.z1` items on each click ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes it does, when the user clicks the start button multiples times it will add more click handlers to the button.

Answer (score 5):

Alert won't fire for new elements because you never bind events to them. Instead delegate click event to the body, where it will bubble eventually:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'z1') {
        alert('fsdfs');
    }
}, false);

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',function() {
    var gg = '<input type="button" value="Button1" class="z1"><input type="button" value="Button2" class="z1">';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', gg);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Start" id="start">
```

Just remember in case of delegated events you need to check that event occurred on the right element. Like in the demo you can check event target class name.

Comment: You're right that a check is needed. A button is an element without children, but an `a` element with an image inside it will cause the click not to alert. Recursively walking up the DOM tree is needed then. Still the cleanest solution!

Comment: @Mouser Very good point. For the sake of simplicity I decided not to overcomplicate this particular example, providing that in this case target elements are not supposed to have children.

Comment: I get it. There was a question on this site last, that I just thought of in relation to your solution. An click on a link didn't work as expected. This was caused by just such a generic body click script as your solution. This solution should be used with care.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector will select nothing from the HTML you have shown, however, if your selector was working, then this is the correct code

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inp, function(item, i, arr) {
      item.addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert('fsdfs');
      }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer to this problem, but a (better) solution to the underlaying implementation.

I recommend to use this alternative function:

```
// forEach method, could be shipped as part of an Object Literal/Module
var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); // passes back stuff we need
  }
};

// Usage:
// optionally change the scope as final parameter too, like ECMA5
var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('li');
forEach(myNodeList, function (index, value) {
    console.log(index, value); // passes index + value back!
});
```

There's a very good and detailed blog post (by a Googler) [here](http://toddmotto.github.io/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/), expaining the `[].forEach.call(NodeList)`-hack and why you should avoid using it.

*EDIT: I know that an answer should preferable contain the relevant parts of any external references. However, I couldn't say it any better *and* it's a github.io link, which shouldn't vanish soon.*

Comment: *"Not directly an answer to this problem,"* - Not actually an answer to the problem the OP is having at all, given the problem with trying to use `.querySelectorAll()` on elements that don't exist yet. (Also, not all of the reasons in that blog post are *good* reasons. E.g., #2 is just wrong in that it ignores the fact that you don't have to use an anonymous function.)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a <strike>complete</strike> different approach:

```js
// Objects could hold additional attributes to be set in addBtns();
// see http://fiddle.jshell.net/eyecatchup/e39wwzwu/2/show/light/ for details.
var btnMap = [{val: 'Button1'}, {val: 'Button2'}],
startBtn = document.getElementById('start'); 

function addBtns() {
  for (i in btnMap) {
    var _el = startBtn.cloneNode(!0, !1);
    _el.removeAttribute('id'); // remove id property of source node!
    _el.value = btnMap[i].val;
    _el.setAttribute('onclick', "alert('fsdfs')");
    _el.className = 'z1'; // optional!
    startBtn && startBtn.parentNode.appendChild(_el);
  }
}

(function(){
  startBtn && startBtn.addEventListener('click', addBtns);
})();
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:10px;} .z1{margin-left:10px; font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Start" id="start">
```